# Hard Code Logistic Regression Scoring Code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression, scoring

I am trying to hard code a logistic regression equation in Python 2.7. I have created a pandas dataframe called df which contains the necessary variables for the equation.

```
#  score equation 
xb = [(-0.2962) 
      + (df['wBCC7800'] * 0.4273) 
      + (df['wBCX7110'] * 0.4761) 
      + (df['wALL7320'] * 0.4061) 
      + (df['wBCC5400'] * 0.439) 
      + (df['wREH7110'] * 0.322) 
      + (df['wBCN0300'] * 0.3241) 
      + (df['wBCN8220'] * 0.2148) 
      + (df['wBCA7212'] * 0.1905)] 

def sigmoid(xb):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-xb))

df['score'] = df.apply(sigmoid, axis=1)
```

This code results in the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ca9845eb630d> in <module>()
     13     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-xb))
     14 
---> 15 df['score'] = df.apply(sigmoid, axis=1)

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-30-ca9845eb630d> in sigmoid(xb)
     11 
     12 def sigmoid(xb):
---> 13     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-xb))
     14 
     15 df['score'] = df.apply(sigmoid, axis=1)

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __neg__(self)
   1121         elif (is_numeric_dtype(values) or is_timedelta64_dtype(values)
   1122                 or is_object_dtype(values)):
-> 1123             arr = operator.neg(values)
   1124         else:
   1125             raise TypeError("Unary negative expects numeric dtype, not {}"

TypeError: ("bad operand type for unary -: 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I want to create a new variable in the dataframe that contains the logistic regression score.

Comment: looks like some of those columns are of type object containing a str. They are supposed to contained numeric values, so try converting them first.

Comment: The equation seems to work.  I can submit print(xb) and it will print out a list of values.  Also, the def does not result in an error, so I assume that it is working as well.  It is the step where I want to create a new variable labeled 'score' is where the error occurs.

Comment: function definitions don't execute anything, so don't assume it's working well or otherwise until you use them. Remove the [] around the xb equation, you are making a list. The str issue is still there. strings are printable, so printing a value means nothing really. You have to verify your column types in xb.dtypes